# Android USB Debugging on Mac OS X 10.9.1

Tags: usb-debugging, macos

I have installed Mavericks on my computer. Before I had Mavericks, I could plug my Android device into the USB port and it would show up in the Finder and the 'USB Debugging' display would show on the phone.

Now, when I plug in the phone, the computer acts as if the phone does not exist and the phone does not show the USB Debugging thing.

I have been developing Android Apps for two years and this issue is mind bending. I have all the necessary Developer Settings on my phone turned on. This has been tested on multiple Android devices with all different versions of Android. The problem is the computer, not Android.

Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: Not me. But have you checked whether the device still gets detected as *USB device* (on Linux, that can be done using the `lsusb` command – I'm not sure, but guess Mac has something similar)? If it does, are the vendor and device IDs still the same? Also, if I get it right, "have Mavericks" means you've updated your OS. Maybe you need to reconfigure something there? You don't write what Android device this is about. Please [edit] your question, and also include the Android version involved, and what USB mode you were using (MTP, UMS).

Comment: Furthermore, if you're not talking about an ADB connection, *USB debugging* is not needed for that. Try switching it off, and see whether that helps. There were reportings where *USB debugging* interfered with UMS/MTP connections.

Comment: It occurs for all Android versions and devices I can get my hands on. I have tried it with API 8 on up. We have them all here in the office. It does not show up as a USB device anywhere on the computer. Doesn't matter if I connect it as a Media Device, through ADB, or as a USB Mass Storage.

Comment: Other USB Mass Storage (e.g. standard external USB disks) showing up fine? That should be the same as an Android device in USM mode. Just to rule out general USB problems on that Mac, could you try any other USB devices you can get your hands on?

Comment: All other USB devices work fine. Thumb drives, SD cards, iPad, iPhone. Its all problems with Android. Maybe something with the USB drivers (which I know nothing about)...

Comment: Wait a sec. If thumb drives and SDCards work, an Android device in UMS mode should do as well. Have you tried the Android device in UMS mode on a different machine (but with the same cable, and with a different cable)? Maybe it's not related to Maverick, but just coincidentally happening at the same time, and the "broke" is either the cable or the device? As you tried with different devices, rather the cable maybe (if you used the same cable always, that is)?